# Vue3 reactive ref inside another ref doesn't update

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm wondering why reactive value inside `ref()` is not working as expected

I use pinia within nuxt3, but I think question is vue composition api related.
`order_price` is `ObjectRefImpl` type

Looking to drop watch function or an advice how to compose differently. My current code looks like bad practise

```js
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useLocationStore } from '~/store'

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useLocationStore()
    const { order_price } = storeToRefs(store)

    const items = ref([
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Foo',
        body: `<p>Bar — ${order_price.value}</p>`, // not updated when order_price change
      },
    ])
    
    // workaround
    watch(
      () => order_price.value,
      (price) => {
        items.value[0].body = `<p>Bar — ${price} $</p>`
      }
    )

    return {
      store,
      items,
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: The ref is for primitive types (string, number, boolean), I always use reactive for arrays (and objects). You can try use reactive instead of ref

Comment: it's fine to use `ref` with objects, in fact `ref` under the hood uses `reactive`.  as long as you unwrap the inner value with `.value` you can use objects, arrays, etc. with `ref`.  what OP is missing is just because `items` is reactive doesn't mean it's going to automatically recompute it's value base on some other dependency (order_price).  for that, `items` should be a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example)

Comment: Actually, `order_price` is not a dependency of `items`. It is used only for the initial value.